# Watir - How to get option's attribute (aside from key and value)

Tags: watir

I'm trying to inspect a select_list element with options that have a custom attribute. Like in the following example, each option has a "title"

```
<select id="mySelectList">
  <option title="title1" value="1">Title 1</option>
  <option title="title2" value="2">Title 2</option>
  <option title="title3" value="3">Title 3</option>
</select>
```

I need access to the options' title, but each option doesn't really respond to the attribute_value method. Is it possible to retrieve values of a custom attribute for options in Watir?

I'm using watir and IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the HTML you have provided, this worked for me, using watir-webdriver and Firefox:

```
browser.option(:text => "Title 3").attribute_value "title"
=> "title3"
```

If you need all of them:

```
browser.options.each {|option| puts option.attribute_value "title" }
```

outputs

```
title1
title2
title3
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that we're using 'watir' and IE. I'm new to this and I didn't realize the difference between 'watir' and 'watir-webdriver'. Does this mean I need to switch to watir-webdriver in order to do this?

Comment: To do the above, yes. To do it with watir gem, see my other answer.

Comment: If you want cross browser support (e.g. to test against current versions of any browser other than IE) then it's worth investigating just moving to watir-webdriver.  The IE driver side is a tiny bit weak compared to Watir (webdriver developer bias??) but the cross browser support IMHO makes up for it

Answer (score 0):

Using watir gem (2.0.2) and Internet Explorer 9:

```
browser.element(:css => "option").attribute_value "title"
=> "title1"
```

or

```
browser.select_list(:id => "mySelectList").elements.each {|option| puts option.attribute_value "title" }
```

outputs

```
title1
title2
title3
```